# WebSphere Application Server 8 Enhanced EAR shared library bug?

Tags: websphere, websphere-8

I have posted this question on the IBM forums but just in case no answer comes from there I thought I would try my luck here.

I have just upgraded my version of WebSphere Application Server for Developers from 7.0.0.19 to 8.0.0.1. I notice what looks to be a bug in WAS 8. I have an Enhanced EAR, I have a build that creates it. I include a libraries.xml file as well as a deployment.xml in the root of the EAR archive. The application references one shared library. When I deploy the application to WAS 8 the shared library reference does not get configured correctly. When I go into the Admin Console I see that for some reason WAS has surround my library name with quotes. So instead of:
Spring 3.0.5.RELEASE

it looks like:
"Spring 3.0.5.RELEASE"

I can manually fix this in the Admin Console. This didn't occur in WAS 7 at all so I can only assume it is a bug. I have tested this off Windows XP and AIX and the same behaviour occurs.

Is there an open issue for this? I don't know where I can search / track open issues for WebSphere. If there is a site to search for open issues please can someone forward me the link to that.

Is there a work around to this so that I don't have to manually set the shared library each time I deploy the application?

thanks

Comment: This does sound like a product issue.  I would recommend opening a PMR with IBM if possible.  I might guess that the issue is the space; perhaps try "Spring-3.0.5.RELEASE" instead?

Comment: @bkail thanks removing the space got rid of the problem (still works in was 7 though). If you answer the question I will accept your answer

Comment: Sure.  I'm glad you were able to workaround the issue.  I agree that there is something wrong with 8.0 if the same EAR works fine on 7.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a product issue.  I would recommend opening a PMR with IBM if possible.

(I might guess that the issue is the space; perhaps try "Spring-3.0.5.RELEASE" instead?)

Answer (score 0):

Hi the problem is with a special characters, I had the same problem and I solved changed the blank spaces for underline, in your case Spring_3.0.5.RELEASE maybe you will need quiet the dot too... is better if you try Spring_3005_RELEASE